# SharePoint Server 2010 change Domain Controller to RODC

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint-2010, rodc

i'm struggeling with the SharePoint Server 2010.
I moved my SPS 2010 into a DMZ within the same site as my RODC.
The SPS 2010 should get AD information from the RODC, but however, it dosen't, since it always tries to use the DC for such a matter.

How can i define the RODC/DC to use for the SPS 2010 ?

Thanks !

Comment: When you say "get AD information from the RODC", are you talking about authenticating users against it? Or are you talking about user profile synchronization?

Comment: I'm talking about authenticating user against the AD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that it is not SharePoint, but the *client*, that authenticates against the Active Directory.

If I have 3 Sites:

> Site A - Domain Controller, 1 client (ClientA)
>
> Site B - RODC, SharePoint Server, 1 client (ClientB)
>
> Site C - No DC's, 1 client (ClientC)

1. ClientA tries to log in to a Sharepoint Site, the client authenticates against a site local Domain Controller, that is, the one in Site A.
2. ClientB tries to log in to a Sharepoint Site, the client, again, authenticates against a site local Domain Controller, here it is the RODC in Site B
3. ClientC tries to log in to a Sharepoint Site, the client authenticates against either:

   1. A Domain Controller that serves [Automatic Site Coverage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732322(WS.10).aspx) for Site C
   2. A Domain Controller within the site for which the [Site Link Cost](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784142(WS.10).aspx) is the lowest from Site C

Comment: I missed out that point totaly. But this now leaded me to another problem existing with the RODC. Thanks !